# Symfony2: init EntityType field with empty data

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a field (`EntityType` => select in the view) in my `FormBuilder` that I want it to be in initialized with empty data so I can fill it after that in the view via ajax.
So I have read [symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choices) about `EntityType` and I found the **`choices`** attribute that receives an array of data, so I gave it an empty one `'choices' => array()` and it did the trick.
Now the problem is when I submit the form, symfony don't know anymore the type of the field and give me `null`.
**This is the builder:**

```
$buidler->add('supplier', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'SBC\TiersBundle\Entity\Supplier',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'uk-select uk-select-supplier'
                ),
                'choices' => array(),
            ))
```

As you can see the the type of the field is `SBC\TiersBundle\Entity\Supplier` but after submit symfony gives me null !
What should I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: can you post the code on controller side where you create a new instance of the form

Comment: @zizoujab Thnx for your answer I already found the solution it's the second answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, this is the solution:
First, I need to pass the `EntityManager` to my form, and to do this I have created a service:

```
services:
    payment.supplier.form:
        class: SBC\PaymentBundle\Form\PaymentSupplierType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: form_em }
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Then call the `EntityManager` in the `__construct` function:

```
 private $em;
 private $supplier;

 function __construct(EntityManager $em)
 {
    $this->em = $em;
 }
```

Second, I need to add two events to the form:
**PRE_SUBMIT** (to get supplier's code and create Supplier object using the EntityManager):

```
$builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event){
                $data = $event->getData();
                $code = $data['supplier'];
                $this->supplier = $this->em->getRepository('TiersBundle:Supplier')->find($code);
            }
        );
```

And finally, use the **POST_SUBMIT** event to set the supplier object in the submitted data:

```
$builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event){
                $object = $event->getData();
                $object->setSupplier($this->supplier);
                $event->setData($object);

            }
        );
```

Thanx to Виталий Бойко who gave me a hint about the form events.
So this is what I did with my knowledge and if you have a better solution please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony by default use security for forms, so if you didn't have choices in form builder, you can't pass custom choices to the form after render only via javascript, because you get not valid form. You need to create eventlistener for the form. Check this link for more information[enter link description here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html), here you can find how to add choices.
P.S. sorry for my English)

Comment: Thnx for your answer but my entity should be an instance of SBC\TiersBundle\Entity\Supplier and I don't have access to query_builder inside FormEvent to get the entity from database by it's id.